# "null" values shown in form fields in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-2, forms

I use Html helpers to display model data in form fields, e.g. Html.TextBoxFor, Html.TextAreaFor.

When the model values are null, I would expect the values should be empty in the form fields. They are displayed normally in Safari and Firefox, i.e. empty, but in IE, they are shown as "null" in a text field (see image below).

[image]

Any clue how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: I just found out that, it's not ASP.NET MVC's problem; it's JavaScript... :p  I am still investigating the cause though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it turned out to be JavaScript's problem (with IE, that is). In the following statement, if `value == null`, IE would display `null` in the textbox (or textarea).

```
$('#someTextBox').val(value);
```

The quick fix is simply display an empty string instead...

```
$('#someTextBox').val(value == null ? '' : value);
```

Comment: Since we're working with strings here, assuming it's the string '0', it doesn't matter, it'll show '0'.

Comment: I am not sure it's a good assumption, provided the posted solution is fairly generalised.